# How to run the Homebrew installer under Rosetta 2 on M1 Macbook

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I'm on the M1 MacBook.
This is the error when I try to install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Homebrew is not (yet) supported on ARM processors!
Rerun the Homebrew installer under Rosetta 2.
If you really know what you are doing and are prepared for a very broken experience you can use another installation option for installing on ARM:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
```

So how do I "Rerun the Homebrew installer under Rosetta 2."?

Answer (score 170):

Got an answer from a developer in the Homebrew github https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9173

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Use this to install packages:

```
arch -x86_64 brew install <package>
```

If you have not yet installed Rosetta 2 to emulate Intel CPUs on ARM Macs, you will get the error `arch: posix_spawnp: /bin/bash: Bad CPU type in executable`.

Prompt a Rosetta 2 installation with:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Comment: and if this does not work? the one-line install command fails with the same error message ("unsupported on m1") when I prefix `arch -x86_64`. any hints? i seem to be the only one with the problem.

also - tried running the terminal with rosetta (same), and yes I did install rosetta. any help appreciated!

Comment: okay, out of a hunch I changed my terminal login shell to `bash` instead of whatever is default in big sur (probably zsh). then it worked. took me just 3 days, maybe it helps someone else :)

Comment: @flypenguin Did you run `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` first? If so, did you try restarting the Terminal and/or your machine after that? It's possible that macOS doesn't recognize that it can now run x86_64 code until you do that.

Comment: I had been struggling for a day or so on my new mac mini m1 to make PHP work with SQL Server. This did the trick. To install SQL Server extensions for PHP, follow the instructions found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver17, but make sure to use the prefix brew by arch -x86_64.

Comment: I got an error:

```
Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.
```

This solved it for me:
`arch -x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew install node@10`

Answer (score 75):

I have two instances of brew installed, the Intel version that runs using Rosetta2 and which installs to `/usr/local/bin` and the Arm version that runs natively and installs to `/opt/homebrew/bin`. Now it is all working, I do not have to start iTerm using Rosetta.

I have these aliases to reach the two versions.

```
ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'
mbrew='arch -arm64e /opt/homebrew/bin/brew'
```

I have the native version in my path first:

```
path=( /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/opt /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/Apple/usr/bin )
```

Now I can try `mbrew search` and `mbrew install`. If they work, I am good to go with a native program. For example:

```
mbrew install ag
```

If `brew` fails I try building from source, with verbose output, e.g.

```
mbrew install -sv rust
```

Be warned, this takes a while and may still fail.

If it still fails, (and `mbrew install -sv go` results in a segmentation fault for me) I have two choices. Use `ibrew search` and `ibrew install` to get the Intel build instead, or examine the verbose output and look for problem dependencies. In some cases an `install -s` on the dependencies is enough to get the native brew to work.

##### I must stress that native brew always prints this warning.

```
Warning: You are running macOS on a arm64 CPU architecture.
We do not provide support for this (yet).
Reinstall Homebrew under Rosetta 2 until we support it.
```

So proceed at your own discretion.

For completeness, and assuming you have iTerm2, Rosetta2 and the Xcode command line tools installed, I did this to install brew under Rosetta (with credit to all those who have posted on this page before me):

1. Copy the installed iTerm2.app application to iRosetta2.app
2. Press command+I to *Get Info* for iRosetta.app, click *Open Using Rosetta2*
3. Run iRosetta2 and use this command from https://brew.sh

Like so

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew' # put this in ~/.zshrc
```

And I did this to install native brew, taken from other contributors to Stack Overflow and the [Homebrew alternative installation site](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation), **using iTerm2 without Open Using Rosetta2**

```
mkdir ~/homebrew
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
sudo mv ~/sudo mv homebrew /opt
mbrew='arch -arm64e /opt/homebrew/bin/brew' # for .zshrc
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt:$PATH" # also for .zshrc
```

##### Edit

Time has passed and I have changed the architecture to arm64e following [Fernando García Redondo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook#comment115899091_65424574)’s observation. Now the warning about Arm architecture not supported has gone and Rust and Go install without problems and without compiling from source. I assume the good people at Homebrew have been working hard over Christmas. Thanks!

##### Edit Feb 21

The Homebrew team have announced that they support Apple Silicon. So I wondered if I could delete my aliases and just use brew to install for Apple Silicon. The short answer is no!

If you run brew from `/usr/local` without the arch -x86_64, it complains that `/usr/local` is reserved as the Intel default prefix and using `/opt/homebrew` is required. So I will retain my two aliases and try mbrew first and only use ibrew if the native brew fails.

Comment: Hi @nigel. I am new to macOS here. When should you use 'arm64' and when 'arm64e' after 'arch'? 'man arch' returns 'arm64e' as M1 and 'arm64' as default arm64.

Comment: @FernandoGarcíaRedondo your observation is a good one. I have modified my alias and reinstalled using mbrew. It works better now, possibly because the people at Homebrew have made improvements.

Comment: Great approach to use arm native and rosetta both of it, but the reason to use Homebrew is convenience for me ;( so I'm waiting for brew could resolve the architecture on its own to switch intel / arm binary.

Comment: +1 you just prevented me from uninstalling my native homebrew installation to get a program only accessible through rosetta. Also, there is still some stuff that doesn't want to install without rosetta, like gdb.

Answer (score 55):

Another option is by going into your applications in Finder, select Terminal and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and check the "Open using Rosetta" option.

Sorry if the formatting is off, first time posting a solution.

Comment: Note that this will default `Terminal.app` to _always_ emulate Intel CPU. Might be useful if you are transitioning and want all your old scripts to work, but may not be what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to run pod install using rosetta on a new mac, and it doesn't work. Same errors. I wonder why this is

Comment: An improvement to this answer - that's been widely covered - is to duplicate Terminal.app and select "Open using Rosetta" for that copy. Use the Intel emulation version for Homebrew. Gold. 

https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/18/apple-m1-mac-tidbits/
https://osxdaily.com/2020/11/18/how-run-homebrew-x86-terminal-apple-silicon-mac/

Comment: This is not the solution I'm going with, but I do think it's a helpful suggestion. Thank you. :)

Comment: @JonathanDagle I tried it, but I still get the same error message. So strange...

Comment: I figured it out.  You have to have Rosetta 2 first installed before you duplicate and mark it as Open with Rosetta.  Otherwise it won't work

Comment: @Hourman Glad you figured that out. It makes sense — maybe? :)

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way to run Homebrew is with Rosetta 2.

### 1. Duplicate Your Favourite Terminal for Rosetta

Find your favourite terminal, right-click to duplicate it, and rename it for easier identification. In this example, I'm using the default Terminal app on Big Sur 11.2.1.

[image: duplicate-terminal-right-click-option]

[image: duplicate terminal rosetta m1 homebrew]

Right-click the **Terminal Rosetta** and go to **Get Info** to check the **Open using Rosetta** option.

[image]

### 2. Install Homebrew

Open the Rosetta terminal and run the following command:

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Running this command will ask you for the password, and then it will provide you with the information of what all it will install and which new directories it will create.

### 3. Using Homebrew

Once Homebrew is installed, you can start using it to install your required packages into the M1 Mac.

Run the following command to get brew help:

```bash
brew help
```

To install a package, you can run the following command:

```bash
brew install packagename
```

That’s all about installing and getting started with Homebrew on Apple M1 Macs.

---

**EDIT**: Thanks all! Upvote to help other devs! Homebrew 3.0.0 now officially supports Apple Silicon (https://brew.sh/2021/02/05/homebrew-3.0.0/)

Answer (score 15):

After I installed Rosetta, I added an alias so I can use `brew install <package>` as I would normally.

`alias brew='arch -x86_64 brew'`

I agree with everyone else in that you need to add the `arch -x86_64` in front of the original command so I thought to include that alias to help anyone finding this thread in the future.

Comment: Why not alias it to brew, for intel brew. Then you can add mbrew="arch -arm64 /opt/homebrew/bin/brew" later to get native builds?

Comment: Hi Nigel, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify? I believe I am aliasing it to brew but are you suggesting to alias to ibrew instead as a distinction between intel and arm?

Comment: Hi Echen, Please see my detailed answer below.

Comment: I added an alias to skip into a rosetta shell: alias ros="arch -x86_64 zsh" - then all subsequent commands run under x86

Answer (score 8):

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Worked on my new M1 Mac.

Answer (score 7):

Do below

- `/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license`
- `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
- `alias brew='arch -x86_64 brew'`
- `brew install azure-cli`

Now try as login. You are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The message is indicating that the installation should be rerun specifically for ARM. You may run below if brew is installed

```
arch -arm64 brew install yourApp
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the setting of Terminal to launch it using Rosetta.
Go to your Application/Utilities folder, right click on the Terminal App and check the tick box 'Open using Rosetta'

But to be honest, I have Homebrew installed without Rosetta. Just removed the x86 version yesterday and installed a fresh version without Rosetta.

Comment: dupe to Khairul answer