# How can I run two isolated installations of Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, zsh, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I want to install and run two versions of Homebrew simultaneously on an Apple Silicon Mac: an ARM64 version, and an Intel version running under Rosetta 2.

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook/64883440#64883440) I can prepend any brew command with `arch --x86_64` to emulate Intel for that command, but this can lead to conflicts for formulas whose dependencies you already have built for ARM64. For example:

```
Error: gnupg dependencies not built for the x86_64 CPU architecture:
  pkg-config was built for arm64
  gettext was built for arm64
  readline was built for arm64
  openssl@1.1 was built for arm64
```

How can I install and run two separate, isolated versions of Homebrew (one for native ARM64 and one for emulated Intel), keeping each of their installed formulae and dependencies separate?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

1. Install Homebrew natively on Apple Silicon (will install to `/opt/homebrew` by default):

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install Intel-emulated Homebrew (will install to `/usr/local` by default):

   ```
   arch --x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```

   *If you haven't yet installed Rosetta 2, you'll need to run `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` first.*
3. Create an alias for Intel homebrew. I'm calling mine `brow` because O for old. But hey you do your own thing.

   In `~/.zshrc` (or your shell's equivalent) add:

   ```
   alias brow='arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew'
   ```
4. Add ARM Homebrew to your PATH.

   In `~/.zshrc` (or your shell's equivalent) add:

   ```
   # Homebrew on Apple Silicon
   path=('/opt/homebrew/bin' $path)
   export PATH
   ```

   *If you're still on `bash` it'd be `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`*
5. Confirm

   `which brew` should return `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`

   `brew --prefix` should return `/opt/homebrew`

   `which brow` should return `brow: aliased to arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew`

   `brow --prefix` should return `/usr/local`

---

If you have the same command installed in both Homebrews, it'll default to Apple Silicon (`/opt/homebrew/`) since we prepended that one in our PATH. To override, run the command with its full path (`/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`), or override your `PATH` for one command (`PATH=/usr/local/bin youtube-dl`).

I also created another handy alias in `.zshrc` (`alias ib='PATH=/usr/local/bin'`) so I can prepend any Homebrew-installed command with `ib` to force using the Intel version of that command:

```
~ ▶ which youtube-dl
/opt/homebrew/bin/youtube-dl
~ ▶ ib which youtube-dl
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

If you prefer Intel to be the default `brew`, add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to the *end* of your PATH instead of the beginning.

Comment: for some reason the `arch` command does not work for me ... :(

```bash
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
Password:
Homebrew is not (yet) supported on ARM processors!
[...]
```

i tried about everything i could find, but I start thinking I'm the only one. help? maybe?

Comment: @flypenguin It looks like you're actually not using the `arch` command, which is why Homebrew is refusing to install. Prepend what you pasted above with `arch --x86_64`.

Comment: This is a neat solution, but I have problems using oh-my-zsh plugins: they use `brew --prefix` to check if the corresponding package is installed, and at that point the `PATH` doesn't contain the 'native Homebrew' bin, so it uses `/usr/local/bin` which is the Rosetta based. Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: vscode has apple silicon and intel builds. If you use the intel build, the integrated terminal with be i386.

Comment: Love ya brow, but why it's "if you are still on bash"?

Comment: @RonWang The macOS default terminal is now `zsh`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I would switch to intel it would say "command arch not found" or something.

Answer (score 27):

1. Install Native Homebrew

   ```sh
   ❯ arch --arm64 zsh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```

   all Homebrew related stuffs are in `/opt/homebrew`.
2. Install Rosetta Homebrew

   ```sh
   ❯ arch --x86_64 zsh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```

   all Homebrew related stuffs are in `/usr/local`.
3. Configuring `~/.zshrc` to use `Brew` defaultly based on `arch`,

   ```sh
   # Multiple Homebrews on Apple Silicon
   if [ "$(arch)" = "arm64" ]; then
       eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
       export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin:$PATH"
       # export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/lib" # For compilers to find python@3.8
   else
       eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
       export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:$PATH"
       export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:$PATH"
       # export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/lib" # For compilers to find python@3.7
   fi
   ```
4. Test

   ```sh
   ❯ arch
   arm64
   ❯ which brew
   /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
   ❯ arch -x86_64 zsh
   ❯ arch
   i386
   ❯ which brew
   /usr/local/bin/brew
   # set alias as you like
   ❯ rzsh='arch -x86_64 zsh'
   ```

Comment: Ooh, nice. Note that this uses the appropriate `brew` based on your _current_ arch (great for cross-architecture scripting), but doesn’t give you two different commands to type from _within_ ARM to choose which `brew` you want to use.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! How does the installer know to put the arm installation in /opt/homebrew/ and the intel installation in /usr/local/?

Comment: Error: `bash is required to interpret this script`

Comment: Also: Why 3.8 on arm and 3.7, 3.9 on intel?

Comment: But anyway, this doesn't work for me - both installations point to the same place!

Comment: Yeah, the homebrew installer knows the current arch environment then put itself in `/opt/homebrew/` for `arm` and `/usr/local/` for `x86`.

Comment: In addition, I install py 3.8 in `arm` and install py 3.7, 3.9 in `x86` all by `brew`. Then you can find that the py 3.8 is universal/arm built and py 3.7, 3.9 are x86 built. So you need to set up respective `PATH` for matching py in the different arch.

Comment: Please check [https://docs.brew.sh/Installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) to find the detailed FAQ.