# How do I install sqlite3 gem on an M1 Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to install the [sqlite3-ruby](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby) gem on my Mac, which is running an M1 Pro chip.

The installation fails with the following output:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220215-37077-7vshdb.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Looking at the `mkmf.log` file, there are a number of errors that seem to be related to compilation process building for the wrong architecture:

```
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib pkg-config --exists sqlite3
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib pkg-config --libs sqlite3 |
=> "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib -lsqlite3\n"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   "
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/libruby.3.1-static.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib -lsqlite3  "
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/libruby.3.1-static.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib pkg-config --cflags-only-I sqlite3 |
=> "-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include\n"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib pkg-config --cflags-only-other sqlite3 |
=> "\n"
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib pkg-config --libs-only-l sqlite3 |
=> "-lsqlite3\n"
package configuration for sqlite3
incflags: -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include
cflags: 
ldflags: -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib
libs: -lsqlite3

find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe    -c conftest.c"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib     -lsqlite3 -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -lpthread  -lsqlite3  "
conftest.c:14:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pthread_create'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))pthread_create; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))pthread_create; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib     -lsqlite3 -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -lpthread  -lsqlite3  "
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/libruby.3.1-static.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: extern void pthread_create();
15: int t(void) { pthread_create(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for -ldl... -------------------- yes

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib    -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3  "
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/libruby.3.1-static.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: 
15: int t(void) { ; return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... -------------------- no

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib    -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -lsqlite3 -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3  "
conftest.c:14:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3_libversion_number'
int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_libversion_number; return !p; }
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_libversion_number; return !p; }
/* end */

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib "clang -o conftest -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/arm64-darwin21 -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/include/ruby-3.1.0 -I. -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens -Wundef  -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib    -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3 -lruby.3.1-static -framework CoreFoundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc -lsqlite3 -ldl -lpthread  -lsqlite3  "
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jay/.frum/versions/3.1.0/lib/libruby.3.1-static.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_libversion_number", referenced from:
      _t in conftest-593102.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: /*top*/
 4: extern int t(void);
 5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 6: {
 7:   if (argc > 1000000) {
 8:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
 9:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
10:   }
11: 
12:   return !!argv[argc];
13: }
14: extern void sqlite3_libversion_number();
15: int t(void) { sqlite3_libversion_number(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

I installed sqlite3 via Homebrew, with the following output:

```
sqlite: stable 3.37.2 (bottled) [keg-only]
Command-line interface for SQLite
https://sqlite.org/index.html
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.37.2 (11 files, 4.3MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2022-02-15 at 13:01:01
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/sqlite.rb
License: blessing
==> Dependencies
Required: readline ✔
==> Caveats
sqlite is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have sqlite first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find sqlite you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include"

For pkg-config to find sqlite you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Taking the advice from Homebrew, I set `bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$(brew --prefix sqlite)/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$(brew --prefix sqlite)/lib` but I got what appears to be the same result.

Can somebody please tell me what's the correct way to install this gem given this setup? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else stumbles along this, I had a similar issue. I have my dev environment set up part emulated and part ARM.

To navigate this, I have two different versions of Homebrew installed. One version is for M1 architecture, which lives in `/opt/homebrew/`. And I have a version of Homebrew that runs on x86 architecture that lives in `/usr/local/Homebrew`.

I have the x86 version aliased to `ibrew`, like this:

```sh
alias ibrew='arch --x86_64 /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew'
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951024/how-can-i-run-two-isolated-installations-of-homebrew/64951025#64951025) for more info on running two separate Homebrew versions.)

OP's bundle config command worked for me, I just had to swap out `brew` for `ibrew`:

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=$(brew --prefix sqlite)/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$(brew --prefix sqlite)/lib
```

Answer (score -1):

have you installed sqilte3 already? it said

```
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

so try `brew install sqlite` first

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sqlite

Comment: Yes, sqlite3 is installed.