# How to install all dependencies separately again for a given package in Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, rosetta-2

I am currently on an M1 mac, and I want to install a package that needs to be emulated using rosetta 2. Therefore I know that I can either install a second parallel homebrew installation (which is something that I would prefer to avoid) or I can use the `arch --x86_64` flag to specify the architecture for the package. But as the author of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951024/how-can-i-run-two-isolated-installations-of-homebrew) pointed out that can cause problems because some of the dependencies can already exist for ARM and that will result in a conflict. So Im looking for a way to tell Homebrew to install in conflicts. So is there a way to tell Homebrew to install those dependencies again/speratetly? So that those conflicts do not occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only official way is to install Apple Silicon in /opt/homebrew and Intel with Rosetta in /usr/local. This is one of the [FAQ answers](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon).

To install them together without conflicts you would need to manually install the Intel version and put in the work to manually move each file into /opt/homebrew.

Short of there being a bottle of something available in the Intel homebrew, there isn't much benefit from doing it manually this way.

The post you linked to appears to be referring to installing a bottle in the Apple Silicon installation (/opt/homebrew) by running it as Intel. That is not the ideal way to handle this and will lead to conflicts.

Your linked post had a link to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/). It demonstrates the right way, namely installed a new isolated homebrew install in /usr/local. Then to install new Intel bottles, you run the Intel version in /usr/local/bin/brew to do the install. You should see no conflicts.