# Install brew in another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, zsh, apple-m1

I want to install python 3.8.6 on an M1 mac but that version has no arm compilation. Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71862398/install-python-3-6-on-mac-m1), I could install x86 brew but I already have a lot of other dependencies installed with my current brew version so I don't want to screw that up.

Is there a way to install brew to another folder similar to a venv in python?

Comment: Does this post address your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64951024/9307265

Comment: This question is not about programming and should be asked at [su] or at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).