# anthoscli ERROR on installing Google Cloud SDK on Apple Silicon / Big Sur

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

I am searching for the solution for some weeks now. A couple weeks ago I received the new MacBook Pro with the Apple Silicon processor and with Big Sur installed on it. When I tried to install Google Cloud SDK, because I need that for my work, I get my first problem. I opened the terminal and used *"curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash"* to start the installation.

After I received the question if I want to help to improve Google Cloud SDK and hit 'N' this error follows. Also when I hit 'Y'...

```
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) The following components are unknown [anthoscli].
```

On the internet I can't found something about this error. The only thing what I have found on anthoscli is that I think it has something to do with Kubernetes and/or Docker. So I tried to install Docker first, only they are not ready for Apple Silicon yet...

I can't imagine being the only one with this problem so I hope someone here can help me further.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please follow the steps mentioned in the following [Google Cloud SDK Installation Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions) to install Google Cloud SDK on MacOS:

1. Cloud SDK requires Python. Follow the next [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/startup) on how to choose and configure your Python interpreter
2. Download the MacOS package from the [Google Cloud SDK Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions).

2.1) Extract the archive to any location on your file system. On macOS, this can be achieved by opening the downloaded `.tar.gz` archive file in the preferred location.

2.2) Optional. Use the install script to add Cloud SDK tools to your path -->

```
 ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

2.3) Close and Open a new terminal so that the changes take effect.

2.4) Run gcloud init to initialize the SDK:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

As I can see that you have use the [Google Cloud SDK Installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#interactive_installation) to install Google Cloud SDK on MacOS. Please try again the following steps to install Google Cloud SDK using the installer:

1. Enter the following at a command prompt:

```
   curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

2. Restart your shell:

```
exec -l $SHELL
```

3. Run gcloud init to initialize the gcloud environment:

```
gcloud init
```

In case you want to install Google Cloud SDK through the interactive installer, and you are getting the error mentioned above, You can create an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/) on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) for further investigation. However also please try to install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions) without the installer as I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for those links. I used those files to install it and it worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

It's a known issue "[Apple Silicon Installer does not exist](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175796508)"

The workaround from the above link is:

1. Attempt install: `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`
2. Run installer manually using files from above failed install `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components install core gsutil`
3. Re-run init: `./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init`

Comment: Worked nicely for me. I normally install using `brew` - it would be nice if we could update the formula to include this workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I got gcloud to install by installing under Rosetta 2.

```sh
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com > install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
arch -x86_64 install.sh --disable-prompts
# restart shell
gcloud help
```

I don't think Apple did a good job of advertising this feature, because I only found it in a random Hacker News thread. I've used this strategy quite a bit and added this to my shell's rc file.

```rc
x86() {
    arch -x86_64 $1
}
```

```
x86 install.sh --disable-prompts
```

Answer (score 4):

I just tested on Apple M1 MBP Big Sur 11.1, which works for me.

Followed [mager.co blogpost-How to install gcloud on an M1 Mac](https://mager.co/posts/2021-01-21-gcloud-mac-m1/)

Full steps as following:

1. Install homebrew package management first

   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. Install Python 3.9.1 use `pyenv`

   ```
   brew install pyenv
   pyenv install 3.9.1
   pyenv global 3.9.1
   ```
3. Set an env variable letting the gcloud installer know which version of Python to use:

   `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3`
4. Download the SDK and start the install, which I ran into ERROR **the following components are unknown [anthoscli, kuberun]**:

   `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`
5. Thus manually run the `install.sh` script

   ```
   cd ~/google-cloud-sdk
   ./install.sh --override-components core gcloud-deps bq gcloud gsutil
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Google Cloud SDK is with homebrew, but Homebrew doesn't have an `arm64` variant for M1 yet. Nonetheless, I've outlined steps to install and use it on M1 Macs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299285/2006016

### 1. Installing `gcloud` SDK

After [installing your Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299285/2006016) on your M1 Mac, in your Rosetta Terminal, run the following command:

```sh
brew install --cask google-cloud-sdk
```

### 2. Linking `gcloud` to $PATH

Once Homebrew has it installed, you'll need to add it to your path. In the last few lines it will show you the path to set your source:

[image: source-gcloud-homebrew-m1]

From the screenshot above, I'll have to run the following to set the command in my $PATH:

```sh
source /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc
```

```sh
source /usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc
```

### 3. Using `gcloud`

Once linked, you can use the `gcloud` command in your terminal:

```sh
gcloud -v
```

#### 4. Outdated Python

In case your python is outdated (see [Google Cloud SDK Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)), you can use Homebrew to update it by running:

```sh
brew upgrade
```

You can view your python version when listing out your Homebrew packages:

```sh
brew outdated
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have MAC M1 chip so you might need to install manually for this i choose to go with Google given method

```
muhasan@Admins-MacBook-Pro ~ % curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

Output :

```
For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Creating update staging area                             ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool                   ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Spec... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool              ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Default set of gcloud commands               ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries (Platform... ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: anthoscli                                    ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: anthoscli                                    ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Installing: gcloud cli dependencies                      ═╣
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Performing post processing steps...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Update done!
```