# Can't install GCloud on macOS Big Sur

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Doing instructions step by step:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart

1. Unpacked archive
2. Running `./install.sh`

Getting this message:
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

And that's all.

```
command not found: gcloud
```

Is there any way to get it working?

Comment: What CPU platform are you using as we have three for macOS? Have you also referred to this link to [install GCloud for macOS](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#mac)?

Comment: @RobertG I tried two of them, first (x86_64) and then (arm64, Apple M1 silicon). I tried to do this precisely by the link you provided, as mentioned in my question. In the end I accomplished my task with web interface terminal emulation at cloud console

Comment: Hi OP. Let us know if the answer helped. If it's useful, consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, then please accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Comment: No, it didn't...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install GCloud on my end and there should be an instruction to

```
Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command 
completion?
 
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

Type in `y` and press Enter and the next lines of instructions will appear:

```
The Google Cloud SDK installer will now prompt you to update an rc 
file to bring the Google Cloud CLIs into your environment.
 
Enter a path to an rc file to update, or leave blank to use 
[/Users/{userName}/.bash_profile]:  
Backing up [/Users/{userName}/.bash_profile] to [/Users/{userName}/.bash_profile.backup].
[/Users/{userName}/.bash_profile] has been updated.
 
==> Start a new shell for the changes to take effect.
```

Afterwards, you need to type `exec bash -l` to restart your terminal without closing it completely.

As an alternative, here are some related links that you might find useful for setting up your GCloud on your macOS for x86/x64 and M1 chips:

- [Install GCloud for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037279/gcloud-command-not-found-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk)
- [Install GCloud for M1 Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086719/anthoscli-error-on-installing-google-cloud-sdk-on-apple-silicon-big-sur)

Comment: Unfortunately this instruction didn't appear for me(
There was only Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

Comment: Please check what version of Python is currently installed by typing `python -V`. Supported versions are Python 3 (**3.7 recommended**) and Python 2 (**2.7.9 or higher**). Check your network as well if GCloud is blocked by your proxy or firewall.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I have Python 3.9.14 and no firewalls or proxy. I'm already on macOS Monterey, but the problem is still not solved. Seems like I need to buy new computer with Windows just to run this command...