# Can't install pyenv 3.8.5 on MacOS Big Sur with M1 chip?

Tags: python, homebrew, apple-m1, pyenv, apple-silicon

I am trying to run pyenv install 3.8.5 but keep getting the error below:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.5.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.5...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.5.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/61/8hkv2j8j6x7d7ldfq1d201b80000gp/T/python-build.20211009182855.32315
Results logged to /var/folders/61/8hkv2j8j6x7d7ldfq1d201b80000gp/T/python-build.20211009182855.32315.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
checking size of pthread_key_t... 8
checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... no
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Trying to install via homebrew. The weird thing is that I can install pyenv 3.9.6. I think it has something to do with that version not being compatible with the new silicon M1 chip. I've tried [Problems installing python 3.6 with pyenv on Mac OS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482346/problems-installing-python-3-6-with-pyenv-on-mac-os-big-sur) and [Issues Installing Python 3.x via Pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349982/issues-installing-python-3-x-via-pyenv) but nothing is working.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 15):

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391/

> 3.9.1 is the first version of Python to support macOS 11 Big Sur.

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/

> Python 3.8.10
>
> ... But there's a bunch of important updates here regardless, the biggest being Big Sur and Apple Silicon build support.

You cannot install 3.8.5, unfortunately.

### Addendum:

Using pyenv and Rosetta, it might be possible to install older Python versions. From [Python virtual environments with pyenv on Apple Silicon](http://sixty-north.com/blog/pyenv-apple-silicon.html):

> First of all, to be able to run x86 executables, we'll need to install
> [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861):
>
> ```
> $ softwareupdate —-install-rosetta
> ```
>
> Now we can install the x86 Homebrew:
>
> ```
> $ arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
> ```
>
> It will be installed in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory. For
> convenience, you can create an alias by adding the following line in
> your shell configuration file:
>
> ```
> alias brew86="arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew"
> ```
>
> Now we can invoke the x86 Homebrew as `brew86` and install [packages
> required by
> pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment):
>
> ```
> $ brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
>
> $ brew86 install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
> ```
>
> You can check whether the installation was successful and you have
> packages for both architectures using the `file` command, for example:
>
> ```
> $ file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/bin/openssl
> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/bin/openssl: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
>
> $ file /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/bin/openssl
> /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/bin/openssl: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
> ```
>
> To install x86 Python, you'll need to call pyenv with the `arch -x86_64 prefix`. For convenience, let's create an alias for this command by adding the following line in the shell config file:
>
> ```
> alias pyenv86="arch -x86_64 pyenv"
> ```
>
> Now you can install x86 Python binaries by calling:
>
> ```
> $ pyenv86 install <PYTHON_VERSION>
> ```
>
> By default, pyenv doesn't allow you to specify custom names for the
> installed Python versions, but you can use the
> [pyenv-alias](https://github.com/s1341/pyenv-alias) plugin to give
> your installations appropriate names:
>
> ```
> $ VERSION_ALIAS="3.x.x_x86" pyenv86 install 3.x.x
> ```
>
> Note that with aliases for your pyenv and Homebrew installations,
> you’ll have to specify them in all commands and locations, for
> example:
>
> ```
> $ CFLAGS="-I$(brew86 --prefix openssl)/include" \
> LDFLAGS="-L$(brew86 --prefix openssl)/lib" \
> VERSION_ALIAS="3.x.x_x86" \
> pyenv86 install -v 3.x.x
> ```

Comment: By default, `brew86 install openssl` installed openssl@3 for me, so my installation of python 3.10.2 via pyenv continued to throw an error. I uninstalled openssl@3 and installed 1.1 with `brew86 install openssl@1.1`. Success!

Comment: I could install Python 3.8.5 with miniforge but didn't know that it's not built for Apple Silicon. Then I noticed later that my builds did not work correctly but targeted x86 instead of arm64. So better go for 3.8.10+ directly.

Comment: I also found it helpful to use the system clang by adding `/usr/bin` to the front of my `PATH`.  Additionally pyenv [doctor](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#pyenv-is-installed-but-things-just-arent-working-for-me) is a quick way to see if things _should_ work or not.

Comment: does this assume pyenv was installed already?

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my issue of installing 3.7.6 using pyenv on macbook m1 using this solution. This also shows how to create a patch file that should help install other python versions. hope this helps.**

[Error installing python 3.7.6 using pyenv on new macbook pro M1 in OS 12.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758620/error-installing-python-3-7-6-using-pyenv-on-new-macbook-pro-m1-in-os-12-3)