# Error installing python 3.7.6 using pyenv on new macbook pro M1 in OS 12.3+

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, pyenv

I am struggling to install python version 3.7.6 using pyenv on my new macbook pro M1 running on mac os 12.3.1.

My configuration

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
$ pyenv install 3.7.6

python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/Python-3.7.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.6...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3.1 using python-build 2.2.5-10-g58427b9a)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4t/1qfwng092qz2qxwxm6ss2f1c0000gp/T/python-build.20220405170233.32567
Results logged to /var/folders/4t/1qfwng092qz2qxwxm6ss2f1c0000gp/T/python-build.20220405170233.32567.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for clang++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this patch works in installing 3.7.6 on macbook m1 using pyenv.

To install python 3.7.6 version in mac os 12+ , M1 chip, apple clang version 13+ using pyenv, create a file anywhere in your local and call it python-3.7.6-m1.patch and copy the contents(below) to that file and save it.

```html
diff --git a/configure b/configure
index b769d59629..8b018b6fe8 100755
--- a/configure
+++ b/configure
@@ -3370,7 +3370,7 @@ $as_echo "#define _BSD_SOURCE 1" >>confdefs.h
   # has no effect, don't bother defining them
   Darwin/[6789].*)
     define_xopen_source=no;;
-  Darwin/1[0-9].*)
+  Darwin/[12][0-9].*)
     define_xopen_source=no;;
   # On AIX 4 and 5.1, mbstate_t is defined only when _XOPEN_SOURCE == 500 but
   # used in wcsnrtombs() and mbsnrtowcs() even if _XOPEN_SOURCE is not defined
@@ -5179,8 +5179,6 @@ $as_echo "$as_me:
 fi
 
 
-MULTIARCH=$($CC --print-multiarch 2>/dev/null)
-
 
 { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics" >&5
 $as_echo_n "checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... " >&6; }
@@ -5338,6 +5336,11 @@ $as_echo "none" >&6; }
 fi
 rm -f conftest.c conftest.out
 
+if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != xdarwin; then
+  MULTIARCH=$($CC --print-multiarch 2>/dev/null)
+fi
+
+
 if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != x && test x$MULTIARCH != x; then
   if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != x$MULTIARCH; then
     as_fn_error $? "internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report" "$LINENO" 5
@@ -9247,6 +9250,9 @@ fi
      ppc)
        MACOSX_DEFAULT_ARCH="ppc64"
        ;;
+     arm64)
+        MACOSX_DEFAULT_ARCH="arm64"
+       ;;
      *)
        as_fn_error $? "Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX" "$LINENO" 5
        ;;
diff --git a/configure.ac b/configure.ac
index 49acff3136..2f66184b26 100644
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -490,7 +490,7 @@ case $ac_sys_system/$ac_sys_release in
   # has no effect, don't bother defining them
   Darwin/@<:@6789@:>@.*)
     define_xopen_source=no;;
-  Darwin/1@<:@0-9@:>@.*)
+  Darwin/@<:@[12]@:>@@<:@0-9@:>@.*)
     define_xopen_source=no;;
   # On AIX 4 and 5.1, mbstate_t is defined only when _XOPEN_SOURCE == 500 but
   # used in wcsnrtombs() and mbsnrtowcs() even if _XOPEN_SOURCE is not defined
@@ -724,8 +724,7 @@ then
 fi
 
 
-MULTIARCH=$($CC --print-multiarch 2>/dev/null)
-AC_SUBST(MULTIARCH)
+
 
 AC_MSG_CHECKING([for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics])
 cat >> conftest.c <<EOF
@@ -880,6 +879,11 @@ else
 fi
 rm -f conftest.c conftest.out
 
+if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != xdarwin; then
+  MULTIARCH=$($CC --print-multiarch 2>/dev/null)
+fi
+AC_SUBST(MULTIARCH)
+
 if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != x && test x$MULTIARCH != x; then
   if test x$PLATFORM_TRIPLET != x$MULTIARCH; then
     AC_MSG_ERROR([internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report])
```

NOW we can Install python 3.7.6 using pyenv as follows (need to be in the same directory as the patch file that we just created):

```
pyenv install --patch 3.7.6 < python-3.7.6-m1.patch
```

**To install other python version on mac os 12+ , M1 chip, apple clang version 13+ using pyenv (not tested but should work)**

Shallow clone the branch of python version you are interested in installing. go to https://github.com/python/cpython  and find the versions available for cloning under "tags" dropdown

```
git clone https://github.com/python/cpython --branch v3.x.x --single-branch
cd cpython
```

Now make changes to the two files in it (configure.ac and configure). the git diff should look like the one shown above. The line numbers will be different based on which version of python you are installing, this git diff file is for 3.7.6 and can't be directly used for other versions. for other versions of python, search for the exact line of code being edited/deleted in the exact file as shown in the above git diff and make the changes accordingly. then save the git diff in a new file as follows.

```
git diff > python-3.x.x-m1.patch
```

Now we can install that version using:

```
pyenv install --patch 3.x.x < python-3.x.x-m1.patch
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not working for me.  Output:
pyenv install --patch 3.7.6 < python-3.7.6-m1.patch
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.6/Python-3.7.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.6...
patching file configure
Hunk #4 FAILED at 9250.
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file configure.rej
patching file configure.ac

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.0.1 using python-build 20180424)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a particular patch (i.e. z in x.y.z), this excerpt from the following [link](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2143#issuecomment-1070640288) could help you:

> I can confirm yesterday's releases 3.7.13, 3.8.13, 3.9.11 and 3.10.3 all work fine on my Intel mac. The GCC solution was not a viable one for me as it caused issues with pip modules that were built with clang. I don't think I need 3.6 or older branches at the moment but I suspect they might need manual patches via pyenv since they're EOL upstream.

I personally needed the 3.8.x version and succeeded with `pyenv install 3.8.13`.

Comment: I have updated my comment, Chris.