# Docker Build Fails macOS Big Sur 11.2 m1

Tags: linux, macos, docker, apple-m1

I have cloned the project, it's working my old machine and also my team mates and tried to build it:

```
docker-compose build
```

but it throw build error for these libraries

```html
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ghc
 libghc-hsopenssl-dev
 libghc-network-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libgnutls28-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I am wondering where maybe the error? is it with macOS updates? or libraries compatibility or the new m1 architecture?

I tried:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

and adding -f in command in Dockerfile

```
apt-get install -y libgnutls28-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev -f
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried it on another machine running Catalina and it worked!

Comment: @Microsmsm Given that Haskell isn't supported on M1, I'm going to guess the problem could be with `ghc`. I'm looking at [this list](https://github.com/ThatGuySam/doesitarm).

Comment: @tentative what maybe the replacement? I looked in dockerfile and saw this: ```apt-get install -y libgnutls28-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev libghc-hsopenssl-dev```

Comment: On intel-based macs?

Comment: On my m1 machine

Comment: You might try running everything under the rosetta2 emulation layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook  . Short version is "go into your applications in Finder, select Terminal and press cmd(⌘)+I and check the 'Open using Rosetta' option."