# Testing Instagram Basic API locally

Tags: node.js, https, localhost, instagram, instagram-api

I followed with success the "first steps" guide [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) to test the Instagram API.

I did it as suggested in the docs with an heroku app.

Now that I obtained my access token, I would like to test this [NodeJS Instagram private API](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) on my local machine, without having to deploy on Heroku only for development purposes all the time I make changes.

In practice, I would like to test it with `localhost`, instead of `myapp.herokuapp.com`.

I thought to add a redirect OAuth URI like `https://localhost:8443/auth/` in the section of the image below.

[image]

As it requires the URI to begin with HTTPS, I guess I have to enable it in my Express JS, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114/1979665).

## Question

Before venturing in such (for me) complicated realm, does anybody have experience in this or know if this is the right way to test the Instagram API locally?

Comment: ok, maybe I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131470/1979665 and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/. Will update the thread when I test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work with localhost, but it was very tedious.

These are the steps:

- Enable https in the local environment (I used the library [`https-localhost`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost)).
- [I don't know if this is mandatory] create a test app* from the main app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps/)
- Set the redirect OAuth URI to `https://localhost:<MY_PORT>/auth/` and update also all other URIs in `.../instagram-basic-display/basic-display/` settings.
- Finally, don't forget to use the client-id (aka app-id) and app-secret of the test app in the requests, which are different than the parent app

***IMPORTANT**: app-id and app-secret are different in test app!

Comment: NOTE: `https-localhost` library doesn't work with m1/m2 MacOS. You'll get a `bad cpu type in executable` error. Either use ngrok (as suggested by @saibbyweb) or follow this question to solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), allowing you to create a `https` tunnel to your localhost.

It enables you to access your localhost via https over the internet by creating a public url for you (e.g https://xxxxxxx.ngrok.io/) accepted as valid URI by developer dashboard.

Also, no need to create a test app for this. Great tool for dev. IMHO.