# Node-gyp error on installing a new NPM package

Tags: npm, node-modules, node-gyp

I have been struggling the past few days with installing an npm package - as my M1 Macbook keeps returning the error as seen below

(I'm not sure if this is an M1 fault or if something is missing with my general config).

My node version is 17.0.1 and after some googling, I also installed Xcode but with zero results.

What am I missing?

```
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path /Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/lzma-native
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
    npm ERR! ACTION binding_gyp_liblzma_target_build .
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
    npm ERR! Making all in src
    npm ERR! Making all in liblzma
    npm ERR! Making all in api
    npm ERR! make[5]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.0.1 | darwin | arm64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.8 found at "/Users/M_1/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3"
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Users/M_1/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/lzma-native/build/config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/M_1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/M_1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/M_1/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/lzma-native',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
    npm ERR! In file included from ../../xz-5.2.3/src/liblzma/lz/lz_encoder.c:23:
    npm ERR! In file included from ../../xz-5.2.3/src/liblzma/common/memcmplen.h:19:
    npm ERR! In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/immintrin.h:13:
    npm ERR! In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/x86gprintrin.h:15:
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/hresetintrin.h:42:27: error: invalid input constraint 'a' in asm
    npm ERR!   __asm__ ("hreset $0" :: "a"(__eax));
    npm ERR!                           ^
    npm ERR! In file included from ../../xz-5.2.3/src/liblzma/lz/lz_encoder.c:23:
    npm ERR! In file included from ../../xz-5.2.3/src/liblzma/common/memcmplen.h:19:
    npm ERR! In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/immintrin.h:17:
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:310:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:331:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:416:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:439:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:461:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:483:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:504:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
    npm ERR!     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
    npm ERR!            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    npm ERR! fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    npm ERR! 20 errors generated.
    npm ERR! make[5]: *** [liblzma_la-lz_encoder.lo] Error 1
    npm ERR! make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    npm ERR! make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    npm ERR! make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    npm ERR! make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    npm ERR! make: *** [.] Error 2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.0.1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.0.1/bin/node" "/Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/M_1/Desktop/notes/node_modules/lzma-native
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting assembly compilation errors on my m1 and the only solution was

1. node v14 and
2. an x86/i386 terminal.

This was how I opened my terminal in x86 compatibility mode, but there are other options listed as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299285/766115