# How can I compile x86_64 asm code on M1 Mac (ARM)

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, cross-compiling, apple-m1

I have a compilers course in college, as part of which we work on a nano pass compiler and create passes. So in the process there is a step

```
gcc -g -std=c99 runtime.o tests/var_test_1.s
```

> runtime.o is a compilation of [runtime.c](https://github.com/IUCompilerCourse/public-student-support-code/blob/master/runtime.c) file.

and I get an error:

```
tests/var_test_1.s:3:12: error: unknown token in expression
 movq $42, %rax
           ^
tests/var_test_1.s:3:12: error: invalid operand
 movq $42, %rax
           ^
tests/var_test_1.s:4:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: cmp?
 jmp _conclusion
 ^
tests/var_test_1.s:9:8: error: unknown token in expression
 pushq %rbp
       ^
tests/var_test_1.s:9:8: error: invalid operand
 pushq %rbp
       ^
tests/var_test_1.s:10:7: error: unknown token in expression
 movq %rsp, %rbp
      ^
tests/var_test_1.s:10:7: error: invalid operand
 movq %rsp, %rbp
      ^
tests/var_test_1.s:11:11: error: unknown token in expression
 subq $0, %rsp
          ^
tests/var_test_1.s:11:11: error: invalid operand
 subq $0, %rsp
          ^
tests/var_test_1.s:12:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: cmp?
 jmp _start
 ^
tests/var_test_1.s:16:11: error: unknown token in expression
 addq $0, %rsp
          ^
tests/var_test_1.s:16:11: error: invalid operand
 addq $0, %rsp
          ^
tests/var_test_1.s:17:7: error: unknown token in expression
 popq %rbp
      ^
tests/var_test_1.s:17:7: error: invalid operand
 popq %rbp
      ^
tests/var_test_1.s:18:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: eret, ret?
 retq
 ^
```

On further reading I found out it was because M1 Mac due to being ARM architecture does not directly compile x86_64 asm code.
**Is there any flag or any version of gcc that I can use to compile the x86 code on arm architecture?**
I have seen rosetta and qemu, but I do not want to running a vm for such a task. qemu-static doesn't seem to work on M1 that straightforward.

The following are the contents of var_1_test.s (this file is generated by the compiler which only supports x86 [as per nature of course])

```
    .align 16
_start:
    movq    $42, %rax
    jmp _conclusion

    .globl _main
    .align 16
_main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $0, %rsp
    jmp _start

    .align 16
_conclusion:
    addq    $0, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

If any further details are needed I would be more than happy to provide.
Thanks!

Comment: you need a cross compiler

Comment: You can't. periode

Comment: If MacOS builds their clang the way mainline clang is normally built, it will support multiple targets.  e.g. `clang -target x86-64 -c foo.s` should assemble.  IDK about linking into an executable, though; that would require a cross-linker and maybe libraries if you're not writing your own `_start` and using `-nostdlib`.   On MacOS, if you haven't installed true GCC, the `gcc` command is actually `clang`, as you can see from `gcc --version`, but if you're using clang-specific options you should just invoke it as `clang`.

Comment: I get an illegal hardware instruction error. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after digging through a bunch more of Stack Overflow answer, and thanks to [@paweł-Łukasik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422088/how-can-i-compile-x86-64-asm-code-on-m1-mac-arm#comment126241107_71422088), through the term cross-compiler, I got an answer on how to run x86 code, or as a matter of fact any command in x86 architecture on cli using Rosetta 2.

[How to run the Homebrew installer under Rosetta 2 on M1 Macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook)

I made changes to makefile to add `arch -x86_64 ...`
and everything else ran perfectly.