# How to install assembly x86 on vs code for m1 mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, installation, apple-m1

I'm taking a class for assembly x86 and I haven't figured out how to get it running on my current version of vs code. I was wondering if someone can explain how to do this or link to a tutorial they found.

Some extra things that may be helpful: Computer is an m1 mac, I have the necessary things installed to run c++ and python, vs code is the 2022 version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422088/how-can-i-compile-x86-64-asm-code-on-m1-mac-arm

Comment: Install Rosetta.  Note that even then you'll only be able run 64 bit code and only code written for mac.  If that's the environment your school uses, it'll work.  If not, better use a VM with the right environment.

Comment: Last I read, Rosetta x86 emulation has limited support for debugging x86 processes, so that might not be very useful for developing asm.  (Where a debugger is pretty much essential to avoid wasting huge amounts of time; many kinds of asm bugs are *much* clearer when single-stepping the code and looking at registers, and which branches are taken.)  Anyway, the XCode toolchain includes clang, which can build `.s`  / `.S` files (GAS syntax), so either AT&T or GAS's MASM-like `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  Of course the asm has to be written for x86-64 MacOS; I think 32-bit isn't supported.