# Can't compile Jabcode on M1 (ARM)

Tags: gcc, cmake, arm, apple-m1

I'am trying to compile jab code (cf. https://jabcode.org/create) on my MacBook with M1 ARM. I do succeed with the first step of compiling jabcode with the given Makefile:

```
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 binarizer.c -o binarizer.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 decoder.c -o decoder.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 detector.c -o detector.o
detector.c:51:7: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
                                         fabs(state_count[1] - state_count[3]) < layer_tolerance; //layer 1 and layer 3 shall be of the same size
                                         ^
detector.c:51:7: note: use function 'abs' instead
                                         fabs(state_count[1] - state_count[3]) < layer_tolerance; //layer 1 and layer 3 shall be of the same size
                                         ^~~~
                                         abs
1 warning generated.
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 encoder.c -o encoder.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 image.c -o image.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 interleave.c -o interleave.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 ldpc.c -o ldpc.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 mask.c -o mask.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 pseudo_random.c -o pseudo_random.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 sample.c -o sample.o
gcc -c -I. -I./include -O2 -std=c11 transform.c -o transform.o
ar cru build/libjabcode.a binarizer.o decoder.o detector.o encoder.o image.o interleave.o ldpc.o mask.o pseudo_random.o sample.o transform.o
ranlib build/libjabcode.a
```

However, when trying to compile the Reader or Writer, I end up with:

```
gcc -c -I. -I../jabcode -I../jabcode/include -O2 -std=c11 jabwriter.c -o jabwriter.o
gcc jabwriter.o -L../jabcode/build -ljabcode -L../jabcode/lib -ltiff -lpng16 -lz -lm -O2 -std=c11 -o bin/jabcodeWriter
ld: warning: ignoring file ../jabcode/lib/libpng16.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
ld: warning: ignoring file ../jabcode/lib/libtiff.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
ld: warning: ignoring file ../jabcode/lib/libz.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x2F 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 0x20 )
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"\_TIFFClose", referenced from:
\_saveImageCMYK in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_TIFFDefaultStripSize", referenced from:
\_saveImageCMYK in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_TIFFOpen", referenced from:
\_saveImageCMYK in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_TIFFSetField", referenced from:
\_saveImageCMYK in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_TIFFWriteScanline", referenced from:
\_saveImageCMYK in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_png_image_begin_read_from_file", referenced from:
\_readImage in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_png_image_finish_read", referenced from:
\_readImage in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_png_image_free", referenced from:
\_readImage in libjabcode.a(image.o)
"\_png_image_write_to_file", referenced from:
\_saveImage in libjabcode.a(image.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: \*\*\* \[bin/jabcodeWriter\] Error 1
```

I already tried to add `-lstdc++` to CFLAGS in all Makefiles, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852568/gcc-4-8-on-mac-os-x-v10-8-throws-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64), which generates warnings of "'linker' input unused" for jabcode and does not resolve the problems when trying to compile jacbodeReader of jabcodeWriter.

Also I tried to compile as x86_64, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422088/how-can-i-compile-x86-64-asm-code-on-m1-mac-arm), by adding `-arch x86_64` to CFLAGS in each Makefile. The error remained as above `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` and

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm no expert in C/C++ and Makefiles and could not find any solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the sources on github and I've checked the flags that you pass to `g++` and the answer is quite simple.

You are linking against a static `tiff` library that wasn't build for your architecture. Look at the folder to which you point with the `-L` flag.

The author states that he tested it on his ubuntu machine so presumably it is build for the `amd64` architecture.

To solve this you need to get the dependencies that you link (`tiff` is one of them) for your machine and link against it. On MacOS that is usually done using the `homebrew` package manager.