# How to use lipo to convert c++ output file from arm64 to x86_32/ x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, lipo, dr-memory

I started programming with c++ since a while but was using Xcode only or terminal occasionally to compile my .cpp file.
Recently, our instructor suggested we use Valgrind for memory leaks but I figured Valgrind was unavailable for my M2 Mac.

So, upon asking for alternative, I was suggested Dr. Memory.
Now, while installing and setting up Dr. Memory, I came across this step mentioned to set up my application for drmemory to run a chekck.
[Image of the step listed in the dr. memory website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzAIi.png)

[link to original website](https://drmemory.org/page_prep.html)
The code to be executed looks as follows but produces error-
`c++ -m32 -g -fno-inline -fno-omit-frame-pointer linkedlist.cpp -o myapp`

The error is the following-
`ld: unknown/unsupported architecture name for: -arch armv4t clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I am assuming this is particularly because of the -m32 command because Xcode command line tools doesn't support 32 bit/64 bit x86 compilation. So, I set out to convert my output file(arm64) to x86_64 / x86_32 for using dr. memory command.

To solve this, I added the following command to my make file- `-arch x86_64` which seems to create an x86_64 executable file.

Now, I don't understand whenever I use the command mentioned in their website `/Users/name/Documents/DrMemory-MacOS-2.5.0/bin/valgrind2drmemory.pl -- ./linkedlist out`, I get the following output - `Converted 0 suppressions Had problems with 0 frames` and the output file out has nothing in it.

I am really confused what to do now. Need help!

Comment: You can't convert an executable to a different architecture, you need to produce it for the correct architecture in the first place. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71422088/2752075)?

Comment: But if I was you, I'd try Address Sanitizer first (as an alternative to Valgrind). Enable it with `-fsanitize-address`.

Comment: Even when I convert to x86_64, I am not sure how to use dr. memory because the command mentioned in their website isn't working `drmemory -- /path/to/my/app args to my app` Would you know how to resolve this?
I have tried invoking full path of dr. memory but still no results, all I get is this output- `Converted 0 suppressions
Had problems with 0 frames`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat actually, this was suggested by the instructor so I am trying to figure out how to make this work.

Comment: The error is likely because you don't have support for arm32 on your machine, and you specified `-m32`.  I don't think macOS supports arm32 at all, just arm64, so you don't want to use `-m32`