# Errors with installing a python dependency on a Mac M1

Tags: python, macos, dependencies, intel

I am trying to pip install a dependency named fastrank that is currently installing on 2 different apple intel chip. However, when I try running it on two different mac's with M1 chips, I get the following error below:

```
***Collecting fastrank
  Using cached fastrank-0.7.0.tar.gz (52 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      ⚠️  Warning: Please use maturin in pyproject.toml with a version constraint, e.g. `requires = ["maturin>=0.12,<0.13"]`. This will become an error.
       maturin failed
        Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Does your crate compile with `cargo build`?
        Caused by: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index
      warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): http parser error: stream ended at an unexpected time; class=Http (34)
      warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): http parser error: stream ended at an unexpected time; class=Http (34)
      error: failed to get `bzip2` as a dependency of package `fastrank v0.7.0 (/private/var/folders/5l/sppq3g8556nffpc74l_54zv40000gn/T/pip-install-ugbpj9al/fastrank_b60c765ae0df4f76b49d90ab4a21f9f2)`
      
      Caused by:
        failed to load source for dependency `bzip2`
      
      Caused by:
        Unable to update registry `crates-io`
      
      Caused by:
        failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
      
      Caused by:
        network failure seems to have happened
        if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
        https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli
      
      Caused by:
        http parser error: stream ended at an unexpected time; class=Http (34)
      Error running maturin: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', '/private/var/folders/5l/sppq3g8556nffpc74l_54zv40000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-hdyh51_d', '--interpreter', '/Users/chinwekele/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/bin/python3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      Running `maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory /private/var/folders/5l/sppq3g8556nffpc74l_54zv40000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-hdyh51_d --interpreter /Users/chinwekele/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/bin/python3`
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this error? I have tried using a Rosseta terminal, tried downloading and running various packages thinking they would help, but none has worked. Would appreciate a response.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac, there is a possible workaround for this problem if you use [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)). The idea is to create an [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) environment on the Mac and do your pip install after that.

```
conda create -n <name>
conda activate <name>
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
conda install python=3.8
```

Here I choose Python 3.8, but you can choose another version.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the rosetta terminal install home-brew for x86 like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883440/14293274)
2. Then with this command install a python version (e.g. 3.7)

```
arch -x86_64 brew install python@3.7
```

3. Then using the correct x86 version of pip (which is located next to the x86 python installation) install fastrank

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.13_1/bin/pip3 install fastrank
```

To make everything easier (so you don't have to provide the full path every time) you can create an alias for intel x86 pip and python like so in .zhsrc:

```
alias ipython='/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.13_1/bin/python3.7'
alias ipip='/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.13_1/bin/pip3'
```

and use `ipip` and `ipython` whenever you want to use the intel x86 versions

Answer (score 0):

This is to add further details to @Marcelo Archanjo's reply above. Conda worked for me, and here are the steps :

DISCLAIMER - I am a newbie. If what I did looks odd, you know why :)

1. If your Mac m1 doesn't have Rosetta2, install and enable it - [see source](https://www.bigbinary.com/books/learn-rubyonrails-book/setting-up-mac)

   ** I only followed the steps up to "verify that you are using a Rosetta terminal"
2. Install Miniconda3 x86_64 in the Rosetta2 enabled terminal - [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-miniconda-x86-64-apple-m1-side-by-side-on-mac-book-m1-a476936bfaf0)
3. If the error "zsh: command not found: conda" appears in the last step, in the same terminal, activate Miniconda using

```
source /Users/[user name here]/opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
```

4. Navigate to your editor's terminal - mine was VS Code. If you are not under the Miniconda3 intel environment yet, then do the following to see the list of Conda environments you installed

```
conda env list
```

5. Activate the Intel environment. It is "conda activate" followed by the path in the env list. It should look like this

```
conda activate /Users/[user name here]/[intel env name here]
```

6. Under the conda intel env, install the desired python version and dependencies

What I tried before Conda and did not work:

- Installing python with pyenv and using venv
- Using VS Code's build-in Create Env tool[source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

P.S
Ensure absolutely all dependencies you need are installed under this env if you are still seeing errors in your repo