# Azure function not running on M1

Tags: python, azure-functions, apple-silicon

Running

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

in vscode

```
pyenv shell 3.9.12
Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in ./.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.12.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/deniz/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-DualCitizen/Dev/2ndfunction/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

 *  Executing task: . .venv/bin/activate && func host start 

Found Python version 3.9.10 (python3).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4829 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.11.2.19273

[2022-10-23T09:38:17.290Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4829/workers/python
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.290Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.818Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4829/workers/python
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.818Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.957Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '29ac434c-0276-4c0b-a85f-c9e4863577dc'.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.957Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [python].
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.964Z] Failed to stop host instance '3d492f60-0fd3-48dd-bce0-d7cc99da71c8'.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.964Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The host has not yet started.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.986Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '1327f3e2-25e9-4318-bfea-0bac013aff02'.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.986Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Cannot access a disposed object.
[2022-10-23T09:38:17.986Z] Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I tried a bunch of things incl:

- Create a conda environment with supported python version
- Go to the root directory of the project, Remove .venv folder
- Activate the newly created conda environment
- Create new virtual environment using `python3 -m venv .venv/`

I also tried to apply the Rosetta fix as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook) [How to run the Homebrew installer under Rosetta 2 on M1 Macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882584/how-to-run-the-homebrew-installer-under-rosetta-2-on-m1-macbook)

but wasn't successfull. How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems to have been a wild known issues. Maybe this could help: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2834#issuecomment-1206135712

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I kept running into problems with python on my M1 Mac until I went completely to Rosetta on the command line. For that, I did the following:

1. Update Rosetta:
   In a Terminal type:

```bash
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

2. In Finder, type <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and go to /Applications/Utilities. Then duplicate Terminal:

[image]

3. Rename the second Terminal to "Rosetta" (or whatever you like) and have it execute in Rosetta by checking "Open using Rosetta" in the "Get Info" dialogue:

[image]

4. Open a Rosetta Terminal and make sure it shows `i386` when you issue the command `arch`:

[image]

4. In that terminal, install homebrew (per the homebrew homepage):

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

5. Once homebrew has been installed, install miniconda using homebrew:

```bash
brew install --cask miniconda
```

6. Create a conda environment, for instance here a python 3.9 env named `azure`:

```bash
conda create -n azure python=3.9
```

Then activate the environment:

```bash
conda activate azure
```

From here on out, you have a fully functioning i386 Python system. This has resolved all problems that I had with Azure, Numpy, Pandas, etc. on my M1 Mac.

Comment: Step 3 no longer works in more recent version of MacOS: cannot duplicate the  Terminal app. Instead I am having success with this approach: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/456757/101138. Steps 4 through 6 here are still useful